# parent-child unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, exception, parent-child

I have a subview, called DataViewController, and a parent viewcontroller, called RootViewController.

Everytime is try to call a function or set a property that is defined in my RootViewController, from my subview, I get these errors:

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPageViewController
>   setDetailsDataObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6aa2df0'

Code:

RootViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailsDataObject;
```

DataViewController.m:

```
((RootViewController *)self.parentViewController).detailsDataObject = self.dataObject;
```

And...

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPageViewController
>   showDetails]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6880db0'

Code:

RootViewController.h:

```
- (void)showDetails;
```

RootViewController.m:

```
- (void)showDetails
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

DataViewController.m:

```
[((RootViewController *)self.parentViewController) showDetails];
```

Does anyone know how to fix these exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do an Nsaasert statement to check if the self.parentViewController is actually RootViewController instance

```
NSAssert([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]], @"Not RootViewController");
```

Try this..correct if there are any spelling mistakes.

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm quite new to xcode and iOS development, so I never heard about NSAssert or how to use it, especially in this case. could you help me some more please?

Comment: thank you for your help, assertion failed: Assertion failure in -[DataViewController handleSingleDoubleTap:], /Users/kevincuppens/Desktop/Catalogus/Catalogus/DataViewController.m:83
2012-01-19 08:42:47.935 Catalogus[6063:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Not RootViewController'

Comment: based on this .. your self.parentViewController is not a RootViewController class instance.. so there is an error within your code that you have not posted..search for DataViewController alloc in your source code and then post that function as an update to your question

Comment: the parentViewController wasn't a RootViewController class instance, thank you for your help